# What does the sealed modifier represent in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, sealed

I am little confused about the use of the `sealed` modifier.

What does it do?

Comment: Try [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) - the `sealed` keyword, as far as classes go, ensures that all subclasses of a class are in the same file and nested with the super class.

Comment: What's unclear about the documentation?

Answer (score 6):

The [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) cover this.

Sealed classes have restricted inheritance hierarchies: only classes that are declared inside them or are in the same file as them (since Kotlin 1.1) can be subclasses of a sealed class.

This can be useful when combined with `when` expressions, which can guarantee that their branches exhaustively check the possible subclasses of a sealed class.

Answer (score 3):

This modifier is mainly use when you want to restrict the possibility of creating a subclass, it means all direct subclasses should be nested, this is an example:

```
sealed class Animal {
    class Cow(val name: String) : Animal()
}

//It generates a compilation error
class Horse : Animal() {
}
```

So, `sealed` classes can not have inheritors outside the class.

Comment: That's not completely true: Kotlin 1.1 lifted the restriction, and now the subclasses can be located outside the `sealed` class, but should be placed in the same file.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning what is the profit of this restriction: the compiler can check that a `when` statement has all the subtypes listed in its branches, thus not requiring an `else` branch.

Comment: In the >=1.1 REPL, subclasses must still be nested inside

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good, but an important point I think that's worth adding: classes that extend subclasses of a sealed class can be placed anywhere, not necessarily in the same file. That's important to note, since a sealed class doesn't necessarily mean that an entire inheritance hierarchy will be in the same file unless every subclass is also `sealed`.

You can read more about this in [the official docs for sealed classes.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html)